# Laravel barryvdh/laravel-dompdf installation error

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, eloquent

Hi I am trying to generate PDF file and I found this [guide](https://appdividend.com/2017/05/08/generate-pdf-blade-laravel-5-4/)
when I enter this command

```
 composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

I get this error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf ^0.8.3 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-dompdf[v0.8.3].
- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.4.36
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.3 requires illuminate/support 
5.5.x|5.6.x|5.7.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 
5.7.19, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2, v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, 
v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, 
v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, 
v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, 
v5.6.24, v5.6.25,
v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, 
v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, 
v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, 
v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.4.36, required as 5.4.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

If anyone have a solution for the issue or alternative to produce a PDF please share it with me

I had php 7.0.1 tried to update it to 7.2.13 but still same issue

EDIT 1 : Tried `composer update` still the issue the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this command which installed for me successfully

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf:0.8.2
```

note : I am using laravel 5.4 and the 0.8.2 is the latest version of dompdf that supports 5.4